# Problem with listings and color of \footnoterule

Tags: listings, footnotes

I would like to change the color of the footnote bar. In order to do that, I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\textcolor{blue}{\oldfootnoterule}}

\begin{document}
    
\blindtext
    
\blindtext\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\lstset{numbers=left}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]
sigma : matrix(
[ sx,  txy, txz ],
[ txy, sy,  tyz ],
[ txz, tyz, sz  ]
)$


T : matrix(
[ %alpha[1], %alpha[2], %alpha[3] ],
[ %beta[1],  %beta[2],  %beta[3]  ],
[ %gamma[1], %gamma[2], %gamma[3] ]
)$
sigma : matrix(
[ sx,  txy, txz ],
[ txy, sy,  tyz ],
[ txz, tyz, sz  ]
)$


T : matrix(
[ %alpha[1], %alpha[2], %alpha[3] ],
[ %beta[1],  %beta[2],  %beta[3]  ],
[ %gamma

sigma : matrix(
[ sx,  txy, txz ],
[ txy, sy,  tyz ],
[ txz, tyz, sz  ]
)$


T : matrix(
[ %alpha[1], %alpha[2], %alpha[3] ],
[ %beta[1],  %beta[2],  %beta[3]  ],
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

However, when I do that, the numbers of the lines of the listings damage, as shown in the figure.

[image]

How to fix that problem?

Comment: You should type `{\color{blue}\oldfootnoterule}` instead of `\textcolor{blue}{\oldfootnoterule}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if you type

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{{\color{blue}\oldfootnoterule}}
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\textcolor{blue}{\oldfootnoterule}}
```

Comment: So simple solution. I did not notice the \textcolor{}. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The package supports rules only for listings which don't cross pages. I think that this is why you are having this issue. If you want to keep the rules for both pages, you can wrap your `\lstlisting` inside `mdframed`:

```tex
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
```

To avoid the lines boxing the code, you can use:

```tex
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed} [leftline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false]
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
```

This is the result:

[image: result]